# pipe ' ' could not be found in case of modal page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have a pipe in folder `app/pipes/safepipe`.

If I call this pipe in `app/home`, it works.

Note: I have imported and declared it in `home.module.ts`

If I don't use this pipe on`home page` and try to use in a page created at `app/modals/viewdreportmodal`, I get error

Note: I am using this `modal page` on `home page`.

```
The pipe 'safe2' could not be found ("
    <ion-text>
      {{daily_report_desc }}
      <span [innerHtml]="[ERROR ->]daily_report_desc | safe2: 'html'">{{daily_report_desc}}</span>
      </ion-text>
    <ion-text>
"): ng:///HomePageModule/ViewdreportmodalPage.html@17:25
```

I can't figure out why the compiler doesn't recognize my pipe in the modal page.

Comment: what module lists this modal as an entry component?

Comment: the modal page, it is here `app/modals/viewdreportmodal` , in its `viewdreportmodal.module.ts`

Comment: Reminder: the personal pronoun is a capital letter "I", with no exceptions. If you're struggling to remember this, install an English spellchecker into your browser, and ensure you use it before publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 -You have to import the pipe in app.module.ts or the module that is inside app/modals.

Option 2-  you can export the home module and import it in module inside app/modals.

In home.module.ts  just like the img below export your pipe and in viewdreportmodal.module.ts import your home module

[image: In home.module.ts just like the img below export your pipe and in viewdreportmodal.module.ts import your home module]

Comment: option 1 - imported in `viewdreportmodal.module.ts` and even tried in `app.module.ts`..did not work, can youplease explain option 2 a bit more clearly, i'll try that too

Comment: @user2828442 in the viewdreportmodal.module.ts -> import homeModule. 
In Home Module add exports: [pipe]
Can you please share a screenshot of your folder structure too

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the pipe to the module that delcares the `ViewdReportModalComponent`.

In your case that would be the `viewdreportmodal.module.ts`

In the providers array of that module:

```js
...
providers: [SafePipe]
...
```

Comment: I imported `import { SafePipe } from './../../pipes/safepipe/safe.pipe';`  , and also added `  declarations: [ViewdreportmodalPage,Safe2Pipe],
  providers: [Safe2Pipe]` but still getting error   `The pipe 'safe2' could not be found ("
    <ion-text>
      {{daily_report_desc }}
      <span [innerHtml]="[ERROR ->]daily_report_desc | safe2: 'html'">{{daily_report_desc}}</span>
      </ion-text>`